# Pandas split cell tex to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 1 row.

```
                                                             col1
```

0  Term: Fall 2020   New Student: First-time Freshmen   Run Date: 5/13/2020

How can I split the text into three columns like below?

My code got an error - 'tuple' object has no attribute 'columns'

'''

```
data['Term'], data['Type'], data['Date'] = data['col1'].str[:4], data['col1'].str[18:29], data['col1'].str[53:61]
data1 = data['col1'].str[6:15], data['col1'].str[31:50], data['col1'].str[62:]
data1.columns = data.columns
newdata = pd.concat([data, data1])
print(newdata)
```

'''

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to work just with this one row or does the real problem contains multiple rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
data['Term'], data['Type'], data['Date'] = data['col1'].str[:4], data['col1'].str[18:29], data['col1'].str[53:61]
data1=pd.DataFrame([], columns=data.columns)
data1['Term'], data1['Type'], data1['Date'] = data['col1'].str[6:15], data['col1'].str[31:50], data['col1'].str[62:]
data1.columns = data.columns
newdata = pd.concat([data, data1]).drop('col1', axis=1)
print(newdata)
```

Generally this row seems to be a problem:

```py
data1 = data['col1'].str[6:15], data['col1'].str[31:50], data['col1'].str[62:]
```

It's equivalent to:

```py
data1 = (data['col1'].str[6:15], data['col1'].str[31:50], data['col1'].str[62:])
```

Which is where this `tuple` in the error message is coming from...

Comment: Thanks, How come the original col1 is still included in the newdata dataframe?

Comment: Because at no point you aren't dropping it in your code. See my edit, I added `.drop(..)` piece after `pd.concat(..)`